# After packaging my Angular 5 library using ng-packagr, the library doesn't work once is used on an Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-compiler, ng-packagr

Currently I'm working with the following versions:

```
typescript   --> 2.6.2 
angular      --> 5.2.1
@angular/cli --> 1.6.5
```

After packaging my own library with some components using **ng-packagr** (`"ng-packagr": "^1.6.0"`), I added the files created on my application inside node_modules folder but when I tried to run the application with `ng serve` or `ng serve --aot=false`, I get this error:

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined: 
[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mazUq.png)

The versions on the library created and the application which use that library are the same, and it seems something related with the typescript version.

I also tried to package the library with other typescript versions like 2.4.2 (this version is the most stable for angular 5) and running the application with that version also but it doesn't work.

This is the package.json from the library I want to package:

```
{
  "name": "oc-infra",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "DXC",
  "main": "ocinfra/index.ts",
  "typings": "ocinfra/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run prebuild && ng serve",
    "build": "npm run prebuild && ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "doc:build": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p tsconfig.json",
    "doc:serve": "compodoc -s -r 4040",
    "prebuild": "node utilities/metamodel-validator validateMetamodels",
    "translate": "node utilities/metamodel-translator server",
    "packagr": "ng-packagr -p ng-package.json"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.dxc.com/insurance/ui-framework.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.28",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@ngui/auto-complete": "^0.16.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-bootstrap-switch": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.0.20",
    "ng2-archwizard": "2.1.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.5.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "1.7.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ngx-modal": "0.0.29",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.1",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.0",
    "npm-font-open-sans": "^1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.0",
    "typescript-collections": "^1.2.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "ng-packagr": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.2.2",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.10.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript-collections": "^1.2.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

And this is the package.json from the application which use the library:

```
{
  "name": "omnichannel_starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    **"my-library": "my github url",**
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try installing the latest `ng-packagr@next`. This is the beta version, and as far as I know should fix this. And perhaps remove the `main` entry from your `package.json`. Packagr takes care of this

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already made both changes but now I'm facing errors doing the packaging with the decorators from ts-doc. 

The '@type', '@param', '@member', etc. are failing in all my files. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I found this issue on ng-packagr: 

https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/413

The tags we are using for ts-doc are not allowed for ng-packagr.